# Opening a select2 in Imacro

Tags: firefox, jquery-select2, imacros

Not sure if this is possible though but I'm trying to open a select2 and wanting to input some text so it can filter and eventually select an item.

```
 VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
 TAB T=1
 URL GOTO=http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
 ' selecting the select2 here '
```

Whenever I try to select the field it doesn't show up on imacro's.
I tried it out here: [Example](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)
Even with ' The basic ' it didn't show.

Any idea's?
I'm using Firefox.

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION:nth-of-type(3)>ARTICLE>DIV>P:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>A>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)>B" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>UL>LI:nth-of-type(3)>UL>LI>DIV" BUTTON=0
```

This code will click Arizona on the link you posted.

To make it changeable use JavaScript scripting and make the last digit in brackets changeable.

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION:nth-of-type(3)>ARTICLE>DIV>P:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>A>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)>B" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>UL>LI:nth-of-type({{!LOOP}})>UL>LI>DIV" BUTTON=0
```